# Java.io.IoException : failed to bind to 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8081 (intellij)

Tags: dropwizard

Just created project using drop wizard archetype and when I try to run my application it gives me Address already in use and when I fire lsof -t -i:8081 to what process is running I see nothing so I'm bit confused why it showing port already in use. Thanks for your help in advance. [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fezUe.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with port 3000 not showing up with `lsof -t -i:3000`. I had to run it with `sudo`, as in:

```
sudo lsof -t -i:3000
```

and then got the id of the process using the port.